# Web Application not pick up resources

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I am trying to build an application in Eclipse using Maven and Spring.

Everything seems to build fine in my application but once I deploy it I am receiving the following error message:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/src/main/resources/springWeb.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/src/main/resources/springWeb.xml]

I have tried everything as far as changing the param-value in my web.xml file but nothing work.

Here is my web.xml file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
 <display-name>Olympus</display-name>
 
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>springLoginApplication</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>src/main/resources/springWeb.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>springLoginApplication</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
  
</web-app>
```

Here is my springWeb.xml

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="org.olympus" />

 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
 
 <import resource="springBeanConfiguration.xml"/>
 
</beans>
```

Here is my folder structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdgaZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following configuration should work for you. Refer to xml resources under src/main/resources using classpath E.g. **classpath:springWeb.xml**

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springLoginApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:springWeb.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springLoginApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I did notice that. I take it the folder structure is going to changed based on the archetype I selected. Are you familiar with an online resource that specifies what files should go where?

Comment: I use spring documentation as a reference. This documentation will tell you different approaches for placing different xml files at different locations.

Comment: Spring gives you a lot of flexibility to add xml files at different locations as per your preferences.

Comment: General guideline is - xml file containing web components should be placed in WEB-INF. Add xml file containing services/repositories under src/main/resources. This gives you flexibility to add test cases for your code. Again this is based on my experience. You may come across different approaches. Only thing to keep in mind is just be consistent with your approach. Use the same approach all across your organization/company projects.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you won't have a src/main directory in your application once it's deployed. So your "src/main/resources/springWeb.xml" should probably be something more like "resources/springWeb.xml". Take a look at the directories of your application one it's deloyed (or your target dir) and figure out where your springWeb.xml file actually is when it is deployed)